# web part properties panel covered by the master page

Tags: 2010, web-part, master-page

I'm upgrading a SharePoint site from 2007 to 2010. I'm done with all the master pages and page layouts. Is still have however a minor thing that is bugging me. When editing a page, the web part properties panel is covered by the master page components. Is there a way to make the new modal dialog appear instead of this side panel? or what can I do so the panel is not covered?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to add some css on edit mode. Here's a [link](http://www.mattkoon.net/articles/sharepoint/sharepoint-2010-edit-mode-styles) shows how